# Não acha método do Controller

Tags: php, laravel, mvc, método, controller

Estava testando algumas funcionalidades no site do projeto que estou fazendo em MVC, mas tem uma função que não está funcionando mais. Quando acesso o site ele diz:

> "Method App\Http\Controllers\updates::retorna_usuario() does not
>   exist"

Rota:

```
Route::get("/update_user", "updates@retorna_usuario")->middleware('login');
```

Mas eu tenho sim este método no controlador:

```
 class updates extends Controller
{
  public function retorna_usuario()
    {
        $cargo = session('cargo');
        $prontuario = session('prontuario');
        $perfil = DB::table("users")->where('prontuario', '=', $prontuario)->OrderBy('nome')->first();
        if($cargo == "A")
        return view('editar.update_admin')->with('perfil', $perfil);        
        if($cargo == "P" || $cargo == "O")
        return view("editar.update_user")->with('perfil', $perfil);
    }}
```

O que há de errado no código? Eu já utilizei o `composer update` no *prompt* mas mesmo assim tá dando esse erro. O que devo fazer?

Comment: Está com artisan a servir? Faça reset, descligue e ligue o artisan

Comment: Está sim! Ja usei o Artisan serve esta rodando.

Comment: Desligue e ligue, volte a tentar

Comment: Qual o namespace do controller? E em que pasta está?

Comment: Reiniciei o computador mas continua do mesmo jeito. Os outros controladores que estão na mesma pasta estão funcionando. O namespace é namespace App\Http\Controllers; o mesmo dos outros controllers

Comment: E o ficheiro do controller como se chama? deve-se chamar updates.php

Comment: Sim, ele esta com o nome updates.php

Comment: Coloque UpdatesController.php e na class UpdatesController e também mude na rota as alterações... Tem um padrão... Tem uma forma mas ai é outro coisa

Comment: Rapaz, tenta escrever seu controller da seguinte maneira: Route::get('/updates_user', array('as'=>'nomedarota','uses'=>'updates@retorna_usuario)); E vê se funciona. Aliás, gostaria que você rodasse o comando php artisan routes

Comment: Pessoal, nao teve jeito, fiz o que vocês sugeriram mas não deu certo. Eu tinha um backup do projeto anterior  a este problema e restaurei e o problema resolveu. O estranho é que mesmo apagando o controller ele ainda dava a mesma exceção

Comment: Não teve jeito, fiz o que vocês sugeriram mas não deu certo. Eu tinha um backup do projeto anterior a este problema e restaurei e o problema resolveu. O estranho é que mesmo apagando o controller ele ainda dava a mesma exceção. Obrigado a ajuda de todos.

Comment: Uma coisa que pode resolver é recompilar
composer dumpautoload
Esse comando recompila todas as classes do projeto